# Spring Data JPA 1.5.2, one to Many self mapping issue

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have Process Table which maintains the logs of the processes executed along with the STATUS.
Now I have another functionality where user can revert/rollback the processes. So for each process there can at max one successful rollback and many failed rollback.
exa :

1. Main process : Load Data
2. Revert process 1:failed
3. Revert process 2: failed
4. Revert process 3: Success

These revert processes are also maintained in the same Process table so that they will have all the details like who , when and for name od revert process.

```
Table : Process 
Class : Process 
Class members : 
    @Column(name="process_name")
    private String processName;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="trn_date")
    private Date transactionDate;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String user;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="start_time")
    private Date startDateTime;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="end_time")
    private Date endDateTime;

    @Column(name="process_status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name="status_detail")
    private String detail;
```

I have created another table called ***Process_Reverse*** which has Id's of main process and it's reverse process. It will have id's which are present in the Process table and this table can be called as Join Table.

Sample Data :

```
Table : Process 
Process Id | Process name  | Date       | Status  | .....
1121       | DATA LOAD     | 25-05-2018 | Success | .....
1125       | REV DATA LOAD | 26-05-2018 | Failed  | .....
1127       | REV DATA LOAD | 26-05-2018 | Failed  | .....

Table : Process_reverse

Process Id | Rev Process Id  
1121       | 1125
1121       | 1127
```

Can you please advise what should be the configuration in the **Process** Java Class which I can use for the joining it to itself via JoinTable ?
I am using dependency

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>            
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version> 
       </dependency>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "JPA 1.5.2". JPA is 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2. What software is version 1.5.2?

Comment: @BillyFrost I have corrected my wording little bit

Comment: I think you're confusing Spring Boot Releases with Spring Data (JPA) releases. For example, my spring boot 1.5.10 application has as dependency on spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE